# change order grid when displayed on mobile Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

i have grill in desktop :

```
---------
A | B | C
---------
D | E | F
---------
```

and in mobile i want :

```
------
A | D 
------
B | E 
------
C | F
```

---

Exemple : [her](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3XDn.jpg)

thank you

Comment: share your script here in snippet or fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to change order....

```css
.wrap {
    background: white;
    width:110px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.wrap > div{
 border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
}


@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
.classA {
    order: 1;
}
.classB {
    order: 3;
}
.classC {
    order: 5;
}
.classD {
    order: 2;
}
.classE {
    order: 4;
}
.classF {
    order: 6;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="classA">A</div>
 <div class="classB">B</div>
 <div class="classC">C</div>
 <div class="classD">D</div>
 <div class="classE">E</div>
 <div class="classF">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you ,
but its work only format mobile . i want format desktop again